# How to create a file manager that can scan LAN for servers and browse shared folders?

Tags: android, lan, file-manager

I'm new to Android programming and need to create a file manager with this feature: it should scan LAN for servers and browse shared folders (like EStrongs File Explorer does it), but yet hadn't found a clue how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will need to talk SMB protocol to do this. Loof at [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library.

There is already an app that does this: [Samba Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.shank.SambaExplorer). It's open source so you might (depends on the source) reuse it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. It's a kind of soft I've been looking for. Are there any other open source programs like Samba Explorer or EStrongs Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a broad ask.

OK, here's a clue - start with what you know.  There are LAN/s, servers and folders, (see, you already have a clue).  Design classes to represent them.  Start with the top-level class - LAN.  Put some methods in to discover all the servers and list them.  Don't do anything else until this works 100% with no crashes/leaks/failures.  No - don't do it simply, do it properly.  Network stuff is slow and blocky - use a threadpool now to scan your LAN/s.

TBH, though I haven't been on SO for all that long, it seems that the developers here like to be asked specific questions about a particular aspect of design/code/whatever that is not working, rather than be asked for a complete top-level design for a complex subsystem/app.  They tend to react ineffectively to 'I haven't found a clue' or 'I haven't tried anything'.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Yeah, I know that it's kind of broad but I have a strict deadline so I'm kinda desperate finding answers AQAP. Thanks for answering!